Rotating disc and current?
I was solving the following problem:

A metal disc of radius a = 25 cm rotates with a constant
angular velocity $\omega$ = 130 rad/s about its axis. Find the potential
difference between the centre and the rim of the disc if:
(a) the external magnetic field is absent;
(b) the external uniform magnetic field of induction B = 5.0 mT
is directed perpendicular to the disc.

Solution to (b) is straightforward, however because of (a) I am baffled.
To solve the problem, we consider the centrifugal force on the free electrons in the disc. These electrons run away to the rim of the disc due to the centrifugal force. The accumulation of electrons near the rim creates an electric field as there is a deficit of negative charge near the center (that is, positive charge) and a negative charge near the rim.
This electric field applies a force on the moving electrons, however it's weaker than the centrifugal force in the beginning and therefore electrons still continue to move to the rim.
When more electrons reach the rim, electric field becomes stronger; at one point force due to it on the electrons cancels centrifugal force on them. Now no more electrons move to the rim. And, thus electric field is constant in time from this moment onward. Call this the PSE moment (just for no reason).
At the PSE moment:
At any point, $r$ distance away from the center: $m\omega ^2 r = eE$

$e$: Electronic charge,
$E$: Electric field at and after PSE moment, at the point considered.
The equation gives: $E = \frac{m\omega ^2 r}{e}$ (Notice that electric field is a function of distance of the point considered from the center)
$\int_{V_1}^{V_2} dV = -\int_0^a\vec E.d\vec r$
($\vec E$ and $d\vec r$ are in same direction)
This gives, after subbing in for $E$ and expanding the dot product,
$∆V = \frac{m\omega ^2 a^2}{2e}$
Now, why I am baffled is because looking at the way the problem is solved above, it seems that there is no current even when an emf is generated (however small, a current must be present).
The electrons are held stationary (we are not interested in the random motion of the electrons) by the centrifugal force and the electric force. Therefore, no current must flow as the very flow of current is moving electrons; here no electron can move. Making them move should only increase the strength of electric field and electrons start to move backward toward the centre decreasing the strength of the field and therefore again coming to the equilibrium state and no current is produced, after this.
However, not looking at the way the problem has been solved, and only looking at the rotating disc, it seems, that if an emf is generated there must be a current; however there is no current concluded using above logic, which is counterintuitive.
What is happening here?
Any help is appreciated.
The problem is from the book I.E. IRODOV - Problems in General Physics, Q.No. 3.290

Preamble
The first text I posted was wrong.
There was a miscalculation and I forgot to include the electric charge at the rim around the disc in my calculations.
I apologise for that. A corrected version can be found here.
Text
I do not agree with what you have written about solution (b).
In particular, I disagree with the discussion of the "centrifugal force" on the free electrons in the disc.
I think it is extremely difficult to measure the centrifugal force of an electron in a laboratory experiment.
And your solution does not include the magnetic induction $B$, which means that your solution may be wrong.
Because the problem is axisymmetric, express it in the cylindrical coordinate system $(r,\theta,z)$.
\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{l}
  x=r\cos\theta,\; y=r\sin\theta,\; z=z, \\
  \mathbf{V} = \left(V_r,\;V_{\theta},\; V_z \right) \tag{A1},
  \end{array}
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{V}$ is some 3D vector function.
Let us summarize the necessary mathematical formulae in the cylindrical coordinate system:
\begin{align*}
    \text{grad}\phi &= \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r},\;
    \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\theta},\;
    \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z} \right),                         \\
    \nabla^2 \phi &= \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left(r \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial z^2 }, \\
    \text{div}\mathbf{V} &= \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial(rV_r)}{\partial r}
    + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V_{\theta}}{\partial \theta}
    + \frac{\partial V_z}{\partial z} \tag{A2}.
\end{align*}
The angular velocity $\omega$ and the external magnetic B field are assumed to be constant.
For magnetic B field, it has a z-component: $\mathbf{B}_0=(0,0,B_0^z)$).
At a point of the disc, the speed of rotation is $v=r\omega$,
where $r$ is the radius of the point in cylindrical coordinate.
As the disc rotates in a uniform magnetic field, an EMF (electromotive force)
$\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$ is generated inside the metal disc.
In addition, there is a distribution of electric charges
so that an electrostatic field $-\text{grad}\phi$ is generated
($\phi$ is the electric scalar potential).
The total electric field is the sum of the two types of electric fields, namely,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}_0-\text{grad}\phi \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{E}$ is the total electric field.
As a consequence of Maxwell's equations, the conservation of electric current ($\text{div}\mathbf{J}=0$) holds,
and we use Ohm's law $\mathbf{J}=\sigma\mathbf{E}$, where $\sigma$ is the electrical conductivity.
And further assume that the $\sigma$ of metal disc is constant single value (and isotropic) in the disc domain.
So the target equation becomes $\text{div}\mathbf{E}=0$.
Let us try to solve the equation $\text{div}\mathbf{E}=0$ for this case.
\begin{align*}
\text{div}\mathbf{E}
 &=\text{div}\left[\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}_0-\text{grad}\phi\right] \\
 &=\text{div}\left[\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}_0\right]-\nabla^2\phi \\
 &=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial(r(r\omega B_0^z))}{\partial r}-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r}\right)\\
 &=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r\left[r\omega B_0^z-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \right]
  = 0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
We might expect,
\begin{align*}
r\omega B_0^z-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}+\frac{C_0}{r}=0, \tag{3}
\end{align*}
where, $C_0$ is some constant,
determined from the condition that the total electrical charge is zero.
The solution to (3) is seen to be
\begin{align*}
\phi(r)=\omega B_0^Zr + C_0\ln\frac{r}{r_0}, \tag{4}
\end{align*}
where $r_0$ is any positive constant (though it must have length dimention).
%% h
The charge of unit z-length of the disc rim, i.e., surface charge integration, is,
\begin{align*}
Q_{\text{rim}}&=2\pi R \left[-\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial(-r)}\right]_{r=R}
            =2\pi R \left[\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\right]_{r=R} \\
            &=2\pi R \epsilon_0\omega B_0^zR
            =\epsilon_0\left[2\pi\omega B_0^zR^2\right], \tag{5}
\end{align*}
where $R$ is the disc radius.
In (5), the electric permitivity of metal conductor is assumed to be $\epsilon_0$.
%% 
The volume charge density of the 1st term of (4) is,
\begin{align*}
\rho_V = \epsilon_0\nabla^2\left[\omega B_0^Zr\right]
=\epsilon_0\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}r\left[\omega B_0^zr\right]
=\epsilon_0\left[2\omega B_0^Zr\right] \tag{6}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, the charge of unit z-length of the 1st term of (4), i.e., volume charge integration, is
\begin{align*}
Q_V&=\int\rho_VdV = \epsilon_0\omega B_0^Z\int_0^R2\pi rdr=\epsilon_0\left[\pi\omega B_0^ZR^2\right], \tag{7}
\end{align*}
The charge of unit z-length of the 2nd term of (4), i.e., line charge integration, is
\begin{align*}
Q_{\text{center line}}=-C_0 2\pi\epsilon_0, \tag{8}
\end{align*}
Since we have to impose the total charge is 0, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
Q_{\text{rim}}+Q_V+Q_{\text{center line}}=0, \tag{9}
\end{equation*}
the constant $C_0$ is determined as
\begin{equation*}
C_0=3\pi\omega B_0^zR^2. \tag{10}
\end{equation*}
Thus (4) becomes
\begin{equation*}
\phi(r)=\frac{1}{2}\omega B_0^Zr^2+3\pi\omega B_0^zR^2\ln\frac{r}{r_0}. \tag{11}
\end{equation*}
The (11) is the final form of the electric scalar potential.
Since the function $\phi(r)$ is singular at $r=0$,
calculating the potential difference $\phi(R)-\phi(0)$ is impossible.
The figure below is the $\phi(r)$ graph in the case that
\begin{align*}
   \omega = 130.0\text{(rad/s)};\;\;\;B_0^z=5.0\times 10^{-3}\text{(T)};\;\;\;R=0.25\text{(m)};\;\;\;r_0= 0.0001\text{(m)}.
\end{align*}


This goes to a more general question: what constitutes presence of an electric current?
In cases like this it is often helpful to consider a parallel case.
Here is what I propose:
Create a setup with a van de Graaff generator
For classroom demonstrations the usual setup is to have the static charge accumulate on two spheres. In this case create a setup with a central sphere, surrounded by a slim torus, and make it so that the torus can rotate around an axis through the center of the torus, perpendicular to the plane of the torus.
Connect the wiring in such a way that when static charge is built up the central sphere is positively charged, and the torus becomes negatively charged.
Start rotation of the torus.

With the negatively charged torus rotating: does that constitute a current?
It could be that you will argue that the electrons in the metal do not have a velocity relative to the atoms of the metal, therefore there is no current.
But it can also be argued that we can treat the surplus of electrons as if they are bare electrons moving along a circle, and that's a current.

Example of bare electrons moving along a circular trajectory:
Youtube video with demonstration of electrons emitted with velocity, pulled to circular motion by a magnetic field

Statements regarding emf and current like this one, $\dots$ it seems that there is no current even when an emf is generated (however small, a current must be present), are incorrect.
For example, a battery with nothing connected to its terminals produces an emf although no current is flowing through the battery.
If the disc starts from rest and then is started spinning then a current due to free electron radial movement will flow and there is a current due to the tangential movement of charges in a circular motion.
Once the disc has reached a constant speed the free electron radial movement ceases as the forces on the free electrons due to the electric fields produced by the initial redistribution of free electrons provide the centripetal forces required to produce the circular motion of the free electrons.

So, after the radial motion of electrons stops, there is only circular tangential currents. And the sole reason of existence of emf between centre and rim and not having current is the generation of electric field which stops electrons from moving. Just like the reason for no current to flow through ends of a battery is that there are  not enough electrons to complete the circuit. So an emf may be present but due to some or the other reason, current may not flow. Am I write with this paragraph?

Also, why do you say, Once the disc has reached a constant speed the free electron radial movement ceases, why do say, it happens exactly when the disc reaches a constant angular velocity?

@ApoorvaShukla The induced emf increases as the speed of rotation increases and when the speed is changing the free electrons are rearranging themselves which is equivalent to a radial current.  Once the speed is constant the rearrangement stops.
